# How can a whole list inside an .rmd File be displayed in italic?

Tags: r, r-markdown

In `.rmd` Files we can display text *italic* by wrapping it inside single `*`-signs. But how is it possible to put a whole list to *italic*?

---

I tried:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-11-21'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

My list:

i) One;
i) Two;
i) Three.

---

*My italic list, first try:

i) One;
i) Two;
i) Three.*

---

*My italic list, second try:*

*i) One;
i) Two;
i) Three.*

---

*My italic list, third try:*

*i) One;*
*i) Two;*
*i) Three.*

---

*My italic list, fourth try:*

i) *One;*
i) *Two;*
i) *Three.*
````

This produces:

[image]

Version 4 is *nearly* what I need: The elements are *italic*, but the numbering isn't.

---

How can I produce a numbered list that is entirely *italic*?

P.S.: I render to .pdf. So LaTex is welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution that works for me: Putting the whole list inside a `\itshape` ... `\normalfont` statement like:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-11-21'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


\itshape

My italic list:

i) One;
i) Two;
i) Three.

\normalfont

And back to my normal font.
````

This renders to:

[image]

..exactly what I want with very little LaTex "Overhead".

Hope this helps others on the way..

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\itshape`

```
---
title: "Italic Block"
output: pdf_document
---

## Block

\begin{itemize}
 \itshape
\item [i)] One
\item [ii)] Two
\item [iii)] Three
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. The `\itshape` idea helped me to identify a very simple solution, as described in my answer below. Maybe that's of interest to you as well..

Comment: sometimes the solution is just too easy, glad you found a way that works well for you!

Answer (score 2):

For html output we could use html tag `<i> </i>`

```
<i>
My list:

i)  One;
ii) Two;
iii) Three.

</i>
```

Gives:
[image]